# What happened to Dr. Cid in Giruvegan?

Tags: final-fantasy

In *Final Fantasy XII* We know that Doctor Cidolfus Demen Bunansa (AKA Dr. Cid) found The Ancient City of Giruvegan where he met Venat, learned how the Occuria control the world by selectively distributing Deifacted Nethicite to control historic events and formed a partnership to *"return the reigns of history back to the hands of man"*.

However for Vann and his party to enter Giruvegan they needed to summon Belias, as Esper they only obtained from Raithwall's Tomb having been King Raithwall's esper, i doubt Dr. Cid found the entrance to Giruvegan, went to the tomb to grab Belias and put him back after he opened it. i also doubt that Occuria would let Venat roam around Giruvegan on it's own given they know Venat knows what they know and is opposed to them.

So what happened to Dr. Cid in Giruvegan? How did he get in? why didn't the Occuria try and stop Dr. Cid and Venat from leaving?

Comment: Which Final Fantasy is this?

Comment: @AyaseEri sorry, forgot about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a little bit if research, I came to the conclusion that Dr. Cid never entered Giruvegan; he merely only discovered it.

There is not much knowledge to Cid's history prior to the events in Final Fantasy XII, but [Cidolfus Demen Bunansa](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cidolfus_Demen_Bunansa) sheds some light on his past

> Not much is known about Cid's life before the events of Final Fantasy XII. He fathered three sons, one named Ffamran mied Bunansa, but his other two sons and wife are never seen or mentioned in the game.
>
> Six years prior to the start of Final Fantasy XII, Dr. Cid traveled to the Jagd Difohr on an expedition into the Mist-covered waste. It is not known whether it was a primarily exploration-driven mission, or whether he already had some idea of what he was looking for and what he would find there. Either way, he stumbled upon the Giruvegan, where he met the rogue Occuria Venat, and discovered the nature of the stone of the gods, nethicite. Venat took Cid as their pupil and taught him how to synthesize artificial nethicite, which came to be known as manufacted nethicite.

Why didn't the the Occuria try to stop Cid and Venat from leaving? The Occuria abandoned [Giruvegan](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Giruvegan) centeries prior to the events that take place. For that reason, they were not present to stop Cid and Venant from joining forces.

> Once the center of Ivalice centuries ago, Giruvegan was ruled by the immortal Occuria. For reasons known only to them, the Occuria closed the gates to the city and let it fall into ruin. As such, not much is known about the once great city. Now, a dense Mist covers the city, and monsters wander its many corridors.

Seeing how the [Occuria](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Occuria) abandoned Giruvegan, that brings into question why Venant was there in the first place. Venat did not agree with the Occurian's points of view and believed all races should be able to write their own history.

> At some point in the intervening time, one of the Occuria went rogue, disagreeing with the Occurian philosophy. Venat felt all races should have control over their own history and concocted a plan to create nethicite that was not under the control of the other Occuria, manufacted nethicite. Venat accomplished this with the aid of Dr. Cid of Archadia, with the Emperor's son Vayne Carudas Solidor aiding them by setting up the Empire's war against Rozarria and taking the shards cut by Raithwall from the locations they conquered. Enraged at Venat's heresy, Gerun and the other Occuria decide to bring forth a new Dynast King to destroy Archadia and restore the status quo they had created.